# Problem loading X.509 certificate -65 (In Jammy)

Tags: boot, partitioning, security, certificates

When I boot my system the first line shows:

**Problem loading X.509 certificate -65**

I believe there is some problem with the file type (FAT-12/16/32). But it works without any noticeable problem.

```
Device         Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 *        2048   2000895   1998848   976M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/nvme0n1p2       2000896  13719551  11718656   5.6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/nvme0n1p3      13719552 500117503 486397952 231.9G 83 Linux
```

Need I do anything using gparted? Or, can I fix the problem with commandline?

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

Comment: Are you able to go into your BIOS and then disable secure boot temporarily to see if the issue resolves?  This might be a secure boot problem unrelated to the filesystems, and it's just complaining about a certificate used for signing drivers being unavailable, especially if your system is working fine.  X.509 certificate issues at boot point to a Secure Boot certificates store issue, not an issue with filesystem types (EFI partitions normally are FAT partitions when autocreated by the system)

Comment: I had already disabled secure boot. Thank you for the valuable piece of information provided.

Comment: Can I use *sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra
sudo cp root.cert.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra/root.cert.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates*  command and fix this problem easily? https://thomas-leister.de/en/how-to-import-ca-root-certificate/